# are 1 1/4" screws enough to hang 3/4" plywood?

Tags: screws, carpentry, plywood

I have 3/4" furring strips over concrete wall.  I'm putting 3/4" plywood atop the furring strips.  This is inside, covering a basement wall.

*Will 1 1/4" screws be long enough to attach the plywood?*

1 1/2" wood screws would be optimal, but the local hardware store didn't have any.  Also, I can imagine the tips might hit the concrete and prevent the heads from sinking in a small bit into the plywood.

I can try it and see what happens...don't necessarily need to ask, I suppose.  But, because I often get good ideas/thinking here, I thought I'd post.

Comment: I'd countersink/counterbore 1/8"-3/16" by preference ;-) Might also consider it a good argument for construction adhesive as well.

Comment: The only drawback to gluing the plywood to the furring strips is the strips probably are _not_ PT and may end up rotting if there isn't sufficient water barrier. That would mean replacing the whole setup instead of being able to _maybe_ reuse the plywood. Also, avoiding moisture absorption is a good reason to hold the plywood 1/4" or so off the concrete floor.

Comment: countersinking is a good idea - thanks.  I am trying to avoid adhesive if possible, though I can see it could be prudent

Answer (score 1):

3/4 strips seems kind of thin to support 3/4 plywood, but that aside, if you use more screws that will compensate for the lack of grip due to having shorter screws.

Comment: Also keep in mind that the strength of the entire thing will be no more than the strength of the weakest connection.  You have plywood to furring strips but also furring strips to your concrete wall.

Comment: @jwh20 Good point on the weakest connection - I will pay attention to attaching furring strips well to the concrete

Comment: Jasen - yes, I have slight hesitation/concern that 3/4" strips won't provide as much support for screws as I would like.  I considered using 2x material for furring strips but ended up getting the 1x instead.